# Lattice relations and isogenous elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, lattices

Consider two (primitive) elements $\pi_{i} \in \mathbb{C}$, such that $\pi_{1} = M \pi_{2}$ for $M \in \mathcal{S}_{m}$ with $$\mathcal{S}_{m}:=\Big\{\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
0 & D 
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}) : AD = m >0,\; 0 \leq B \leq D\Big\}.$$
Let $\Lambda_{i} = \mathbb{Z}\pi_{i} + \mathbb{Z}$ denote the corresponding lattice. Does this imply that:
(a) the elliptic curves that correspond to these lattices are isogenous, and
(b) the conductor of the order that corresponds to $\pi_{1}$ divides the conductor of the order that corresponds to $\pi_{2}$, which equals det($M$).

Comment: Usually $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are all matrices with unit determinant, so your $m$ would be $\pm 1$.

Comment: But this is "almost" $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ (with the (-1) as well) and it only gives homothetic lattices (isomorphic elliptic curves), right?

Comment: That is why I think you meant to use a different notation. You may take matrices in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ with integer entries.

Comment: The set $\mathcal{S}_{m}$ I am referring to, can be found in Silverman's "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", pp.143-148. My question above is my understanding of those pages but I wanted to double check that I am not "over-simplifying" the isogenous situation for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$.